# Better file copying?

Tags: files

On my windows machine I have a few utilities which makes it easy to copy/move large numbers of files from and to different directories, Teracopy is the one I use most.  I cannot do the same on my (K)Ubuntu boxes because all file IO operations execute at the same time and there's no native way to queue files; see a list of files currently lined up for moving/coping; pause, resume, stop individual files etc.

Is there a better file copy/move utility for (K)ubuntu?

Comment: Feature request on KDE bugtracker: [KDE bug #259512](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=259512)

Comment: Krusader works for me. I love the GUI..

Answer (score 1):

[Krusader](http://www.krusader.org/) is a dual-window file manager for KDE which was inspired by other great file managers like Midnight Commander oder Total Commander on MS Windows Systems.

You can queue file copy/move actions without any problems - just select the files you want to copy, press first <kbd>F5</kbd> and then <kbd>F2</kbd> right afterwards to put the command in a queue.
Moving files functions accordingly by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> afterwards.

You can install Krusader by opening a terminal

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

and typing

`sudo apt-get install krusader`

I hope you like it - enjoy! :)